# Creating a graph based on input from a file in tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter

I have a GUI where the user loads a log file and can view the log file on a frame with the warnings and errors in the file highlighted.

I am also trying to visualize the data of this file by creating a graph that contains the ids and time stamps from this log file that the user selected. I have been able to create a graph separately using matplotlib and it displays the graph using `plt.show()`.

But I have trouble embedding it in my tkinter gui. I have tried many things but have only been able to get the axes and not the actual bar graph. When the user selects the file to load, the log file comes up etc but in the canvas area only the axes show up and no plot.

Here is part of my code:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import \
    FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

link,warn_list,frame_id, timeStamp=[[] for _ in range(4)]

root= Tk()

Title=root.title("Tool")

label=ttk.Label(root, text="Welcome",foreground='purple',font=("Times 20 bold italic"))

label.pack()

frame1=ttk.LabelFrame(root,labelanchor=NW,height=500,width=500,text='Static Information')

frame1.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)

text_static=Text(frame1,width=45, height=15,bg='lightgray')

text_static.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH)

def loadfile():

    filename=askopenfilename(parent=root,filetypes=(("Text File","*.txt"),  ("All Files","*.*")),title='Choose a file')
    with open(filename, 'r')as log:
        for num,line in enumerate(log,1):
            if line.find("cam_req_mgr_process_sof")!=-1:
                    line=line.split()
                    frame_id.append(line [-1])  
                    timeStamp.append(line[3].replace(":", ""))


menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

file=Menu(menu)

file.add_command(label='Load', command=loadfile)

file.add_command(label='Exit',command=root.destroy)

menu.add_cascade(label='Select an option:', menu=file)

def graph():

    fig=plt.Figure()            
    x=frame_id #can use x=range(1,38) 
    y=[1]*len(x)

    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.bar(x,y,width=0.5, color='lightgreen')
    return fig

plot=graph()

canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(plot,frame1)

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()

toolbar=NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas,frame1)

toolbar.update()

canvas._tkcanvas.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[see the result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beuPY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The graph drawing almost works ! But not by loading a file. The problem is you don't update the canvas with the new set of data, and you don't cast them into numbers (float ? integers ?)

You kinda reach the limit of a functional approach to design this tool, because you need to refer i.e. to `frame_id` and `canvas` inside functions. 1 or 2 classes could solve this more easily.

As a quick fix i suggest this function :

```
def loadfile():
    global frame_id   # reach outside scope to use frame_id
    frame_id = []
    filename=askopenfilename(parent=root,
                             filetypes=(("Text File","*.txt"),  
                                        ("All Files","*.*")),
                             title='Choose a file')
    with open(filename, 'r')as log:
        for num,line in enumerate(log,1):
            if line.find("cam_req_mgr_process_sof")!=-1:
                    line=line.split()
                    frame_id.append(float(line [-1])) # cast to float
                    timeStamp.append(line[3].replace(":", ""))
    newplot = graph()
    newplot.canvas = canvas
    canvas.figure = newplot
    canvas.draw()
```